# Problema con las variables de entorno

Tags: java, netbeans, maven, java-16

Vengo aqui por que modifique hace tiempo las variables de entorno para seguir un curso de Udemy con Eclipse y ahora vuelvo a querer ejecutar un proyecto que tengo en NetBeans y me salta el siguiente error.

```
cd C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\TODO PROYECTO\api-rest final; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_111" M2_HOME=C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Downloads\\maven\\apache-maven-3.6.3 cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Downloads\\maven\\apache-maven-3.6.3\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 install\""
El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.
```

Reconozco algunas de las variables, que son de maven y parece que me faltan ahora sin saber demasiado por que, pero otras se me escapan, recuerdo que alguna variable la tenia en algun archivo de la carpeta de descargas  pero si las redirijo de nuevo a variables descargadas tampoco me las reconoce.

```
C:\Users\User>where javac
```

> C:\Users\User\Desktop\Curso Spring Udemy\jdk-16.0.1\bin\javac.exe

```
C:\Users\User>where mvn
```

> C:\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin\mvn C:\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin\mvn.cmd

Comment: agrega porfa las salidas de los comandos: where javac y where mvn

Comment: C:\Users\User>where javac
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Curso Spring Udemy\jdk-16.0.1\bin\javac.exe

C:\Users\User>where mvn
C:\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin\mvn
C:\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin\mvn.cmd

Comment: He comprobado que la variable M2_HOME este bien configurada con la carpeta correspondiente, pero parece que la sigue buscando donde no toca, en descargas

Comment: abre propiedades y allí revisa que plataforma tiene asignada, al aprecer le pusiste una ruta hacian un java 8 pero en tu sistema tienes un java 16, aparte de que debes revisar tu configuración de maven ya que está buscandomvn.bat cuando lo que tienes es un mvn.cmd